# XCUITest Order of Test Execution

Tags: ios, xcode, automated-tests, xctest, xcuitest

Is there any known way to influence the order in which test methods are called by *XCUITest*? Currently it seems to be completely arbitrary which test method is called in which order.

This makes it impossible to define a specific order. In general the way how Xcode manages XCUITest runs is sub-optimal in that you have to define a test function for every single test case. It would be much more desirable to launch a complete test session from only one method so one can structure their own tests in for example session : features : scenarios.

... That's exactly what I'm trying to do because we're following a Calabash-style test structure and a framework I've wrote around XCUITest provides a lot of additional functionality (such as Testrail integration).

I've tried to implement the framework in such a way that all features and scenarios are organized and started from a single `test()` method. This would work if Xcode would allow for it but as it turns out terminating and launching the app between every scenario is problematic as it causes Main thread stalls or even crashes. So I've added support to our framework to do it the old-fashion Xcode way of having to define a method for every test but the order is messed up by Xcode which messes up the generation of logs and reports for Testrail.

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot define or change the order. In fact, according to a radar by Ash Furrow, test invocation should be randomised: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4937505996537856.

Comment: I don’t think that we shouldn’t have an option of whether testing should be random or not. In any case I figured that naming test methods numerically does seem to always execute them in order, eg test1, test2, test3 and since we got our own reporting measures and don’t care about the Xcode reports that naming is ok for us.

Comment: But you shouldn't expect this behaviour to be ever present. As far as I know this is not documented. It's just the way it is right now.

Answer (score 8):

XCUITest executes tests in alphabetical ascending order(unless randomised). You can name the test methods like the following to run in the order you want

`test01FirstCase() { //test code }`

`test02ThirdCaseButRunsSecond() { //test code }`

`test03SecondCaseButRunsThird() { //test code }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app not to launch and terminate after every test method so simply take `XCUIApplication().launch()` method out of Setup method and put it into very first test function at top of everything, this is how app will launch only once and second test execution will start exactly from the point where first test is ended.

If you want to maintain execution sequence one way is to define any one of following order

```
      func Test01(){} 
      func Test01(){}
      func Test_A(){}
      func Test_B(){}
      func Test01_AnyString(){}
      func Test02_AnyString(){}
```

or if you want to start all the execution from single method follow the steps below

```
     func Test01_veryFirstTestMethod(){

           secondTestMethod()
           thirdTestMethod()
           forthTestMethod()
           so on............
}
```

Note: your `secondTestMethod`, `thirdTestMethod`, `forthTestMethod` won't have test keyword in function declaration

Comment: If all the executions start from single method, any failures in one method will not allow execution of following methods. Also I recommend to launch the application in `setUp()` function. To stop launching before every test and use the existing instance below approach can be used

    `func setUp() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        if !app.wait(for: .runningForeground, timeout: 5) {
            app.launch()
        }
    }`